# Is AMP ( Accelerated Mobile Pages ) compatible with angular2?

Tags: angular, single-page-application, amp-html

i'm developping angular 2 SPA.. I'm asking for the compatibility between angular 2 and AMP and how to implement it.
Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, JavaScript code not provided by the AMP Project can not be on your AMP page. Though, depending on what you're doing, you could use [`<amp-iframe>`](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/guides/iframes)

Answer (score 4):

It could become very relevant soon, once universal is more mature. It could be used to generate a static AMP version of your page.